# Why am I getting an error when using multiple logical filters for WFS?

Tags: javascript, openlayers, wfs, json, filter

I am using openlayers to query a geoserver WFS and am trying to use ol.format.filter.and to include multiple logical filters:

```
var featureRequest = new ol.format.WFS().writeGetFeature({
        srsName: 'EPSG:3857',
        featureNS: 'http://geoserver.sf.net',
        featurePrefix: 'sde',
        featureTypes: ['parcels_il'],
        outputFormat: 'application/json',
        filter: ol.format.filter.and(
            ol.format.filter.like('County', 'Henry*'),
            ol.format.filter.equalTo('Landcover Majority', 'Cultivated Cropland')

        )
      });  

      // then post the request and add the received features to a layer
      fetch('http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(featureRequest)
      }).then(function(response) {
        return response.json();
      }).then(function(json) {
        var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(json);
        vectorSource.addFeatures(features);
        map.getView().fit(vectorSource.getExtent());
        map.addLayer(vector);
      });
```

I can run each filter individually without a problem, but when I try to combine I get this error:

```
filter_test.html:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I've researched this but haven't figured it out yet. What is going wrong?

UPDATE: Upon further investigation it doesn't seem that the issue is with multiple logical operators in all cases, it seems to have issues with string fields where there are spaces in the values. I also get this error when trying to filter on numeric fields using lessThanorEqualTo and greaterThanorEqualto.

Comment: What is the raw server response (you can get it using your browser's developer tools)? Seems to be an error page in HTML format, starting with "<".

Comment: thanks for the reply, i logged the response to the console but am having a hard time finding the content in there - how else can I see it? i am using chrome

Comment: use open url in new tab to see what is returned by the server